# steady distance between LinearLayout items and recyclerview

Tags: android, xml, android-recyclerview, android-linearlayout, floating-action-button

I'm looking for a way to make the `LinearLayout` containing two `buttons` be steady compared to the `recyclerview`. In particular i'm trying to place it like this but with one more button .
[image]


[image]


Here is my xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.a.TSport">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="-26dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="338dp">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.078" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:text="Button" />

            <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/floatingActionButton"
                android:layout_width="56dp"
                android:layout_height="62dp"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_marginLeft="200dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.929"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.942"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add_black_24dp" />


        </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The problem comes when i have two buttons and i add some `items` : for each added item the linearlayout containing two buttons moves down until it disappear.


[image: Error]

Comment: I didn't get it. you want not the buttons to move out of the screen after items are added? you want your buttons to stick down there and be visible even if items filled the screen?

Comment: exactly, this is what I am trying to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first, remove LinearLaypit and use ConstraintLayout.

it's easy

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >


    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/appBarLayout" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/floatingActionButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

but only LinearLayout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:weightSum="10">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_weight="0.75"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" >

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_weight="8.25"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"  />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:weightSum="10"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:text="Button" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="5"
            android:layout_height="10dp"/>
        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:clickable="true"
            android:id="@+id/floatingActionButton"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_height="62dp"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"/>


    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I was trying with linearlayout for practicing. This way works fine but there is a way to do it in linearlayout?

Comment: I'm adding to answer XML only LinearLayout

Comment: I've seen it now. There is a way to see the items of the recyclerview between the two buttons (in the linearlayout version)?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to place both buttons at bottom than you have to make 2 changes

First you need to add `android:layout_weight="1"` and second replace `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` with `android:layout_height="0dp"` for your `RecyclerView`. This will give full size to your recyclerview until bottom views are visible.

You complete recyclerview should look like this:

```
 <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        />
```

**NOTE:** Here from RecyclerView I have removed constraint, because its parent is LinearLayout, so need to use constraint here.

**OPTIONAL:** Also I notice that you have used ConstraintLayout  and it has only 1 child LinearLayout and also LinearLayout has not any constraint given, So if ConstraintLayout has not required you should remove it and only use LinearLayout as parent.

Comment: thanks, this is good too because the buttons are down on the screen and they don't move, but does not allow to see the recyclerview between the buttons